# Running Guice on OSGI

Tags: osgi, guice

I have a guice dependency on my application that I would like to run on an OSGI environment. When I try to run it, gives me ClassNotFoundException. And it seems that guice is not campatible with OSGI. Thus, what steps need to be taken for Guice dependent programs to be able to run on OSGI. The alternative is to use peaberry, but I cannot alter the dependency (I am new to OSGI)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you read this [Using Guice in an OSGi container](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/OSGi)

Comment: As suggested in the link about the classpath property and I did add that in the JVM argument, even that does not resolve the jar on OSGI..